# Where to add application specific property files in tomcat6?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web, tomcat6

I developed a web application and deployed in tomcat6. Actually, this web application has number of property files. Now, we placed all property files in WEB-INF/classes directory and So, the web app is running perfectly as this is default class path. Now, I want to keep all property files in a separate directory webapps/web_application/config and add this directory to tomcat class path. So that I don't have to change any java file for specifying new path of property files. I googled it a lot. But, every one is suggesting to place all property files in tomcat_home/XXXX and add this path in tomcat_home/conf/catalina.properties file attribute shared.loader="" . But, I do not want to do like this as these property files are my application specific. Is there any way to add webapps/web_application/config directory to  classpath . Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Manifest Class-Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#classpath) entry to modify the web-app's class path.

Note that I would not use `webapps/web_application/config` because this location would be accessible from a web browser.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your response.Thanks for your comment "I would not use webapps/web_application/config because this location would be accessible from a web browser". I will change the location to WEB-INF/config. When coming to actual issue, I think, we can use manifest file if and only if the project is in war file form. But my project is in directory structure. Can I use manifest file even if the project is in directory structure. Thanks in advance.